# Very slow vkEndCommandBuffer on Android

Tags: android, performance, vulkan

I did some profiling and found out that vkEndCommandBuffer does a lot of work on Android (25% of render thread time in my application). The most strange thing to me is that it does huge memcpy (20% of render thread time).

I tried different flags in command buffer and command buffer pool, also I tried to reset command buffer implicitly and explicitly, but nothing helped. I found out that vkEndCommandBuffer works faster if I disable MSAA. But it doesn't make sense to me.

Stack:

- qglinternal::vkEndCommandBuffer
- QglCommandBuffer::End
- A5xCommandBuffer::HwProcessWorkload
- memcpy

Why is it so slow? And what is it doing? Any ideas?

---

UPD: I tested my app on 5 devices. App does 200-400 draw calls every frame:

1. Xiaomi MiA1. Android 7.1. Adreno 506. Driver version: 55.277.3829 (according Vulkan Caps Viewer). 30 fps. No memcpy in vkEndCommandBuffer, but it still takes 5% of render thread time.
2. Xiaomi MiA2 Lite. Android 9.0. Adreno 506. Driver version: 512.331.0. 20-25 fps. Huge memcpy, vkEndCommandBuffer takes 25.6% of render thread time.
3. Yandex YNDX-000SB. Android 8.1. Adreno 508. Driver version: 14.307.2170. 30 fps. Huge memcpy, vkEndCommandBuffer takes 22.7% of render thread time.
4. Google Pixel 2 XL. Android 10.0. Adreno 540. Driver version: 512.385.0. 60 fps (but it's expensive device). Huge memcpy, but vkEndCommandBuffer takes only 5.8% of render thread time.
5. Samsung Galaxy J7. Android 8.1. Mali-T830. 45-50 fps. vkEndCommandBuffer takes only 0.2% of render thread time.

Also I noticed next things:

- all devices with Adreno do a lot of work in DrawIndexed. They are calling huge memset (wtf?);
- all devices with Adreno don't reuse command buffers. They always free all resources of command buffer (even if I use implicit reset). It takes about 2-5% of render thread time depending on device.

Comment: What device is this on?

Comment: 'qgl' and 'A5x' imply a Qualcomm processor with Adreno 5xx GPU. Would be helpful to know the driver version, but really you probably need to seek help from Qualcomm developer support or their performance tools.

Comment: @JesseHall Thanks!

Comment: @LewisGordon I updated my question.

Comment: Another question that occurred to me - are you using secondary command buffers?

Comment: @LewisGordon No, I don't use secondary command buffers